# How to say "While I smoking ... "

Tags: translation

I want to make a funny video where two people are high and dance. And I want to write some strong phrase.
Direct Russian translate is "**When smoked weed**", But I understand it is not correct.
So how to say I feel like this while I do this?

Answer (score 1):

When creating meme content (whether still images or videos) it has become common to use the **second person** to describe a situation that the viewer might find themselves in:

> [image: Meme of Gru looking concerned with the caption "When you flush the toilet and the water starts rising"] [image: Image of a black dog with a white badminton birdie on its nose standing in water surrounded by white-billed black birds with the caption "When you lie on your resume and still get the job"]

So in your case you might caption the video **"When you smoke weed."**

Answer (score 0):

"When I smoke weed".  This is a noun phrase that means "the time of me smoking weed". A caption does not need to be a complete sentence.

You can choose between

> When I smoke weed  (I feel like this)

or with different nuance.

> When they smoked weed (this is what happened)